# How to check if one date is later than the other in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got these dates

```
var d1 = new Date(2019, 9, 6);
var d2 = new Date(2019, 9, 7);
```

How do I compare them to see which is later and which is earlier?

Comment: With either [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) or [valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf).  They both return the number of milliseconds from a reference date.

Comment: Remember, GAS is just an extension of JavaScript so, if your question is about something that is not specific to Google Apps, you will probably find a thorough answer by searching in a JavaScript context. Here's a very thorough answer in a JavaScript context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get timestamp im ms from Date object and compare it:

```
var d1 = new Date(2019, 9, 6).getTime();
var d2 = new Date(2019, 9, 7).getTime();

var isD1Bigger = d1 > d2;
```

Comment: Like the Flash!